# Scroll to bottom of div only when new data is added to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, scroll

This is how I maintain the scroll position of div "currentinfo" whenever the page refreshes.
But I want to scroll to bottom of the div when new data is added to div. How is that possible?

```
<form id="form1" runat="server"><asp:ScriptManager ID="manager" ScriptMode="Release" runat="server" ></asp:ScriptManager>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // It is important to place this JavaScript code after ScriptManager1
      var xPos, yPos;
      var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

      function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
          if ($get('<%=currentinfo.ClientID%>') != null) {
          // Get X and Y positions of scrollbar before the partial postback
              xPos = $get('<%=currentinfo.ClientID%>').scrollLeft;
              yPos = $get('<%=currentinfo.ClientID%>').scrollTop;
        }
     }

     function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
         if ($get('<%=currentinfo.ClientID%>') != null) {
           // Set X and Y positions back to the scrollbar
           // after partial postback
             $get('<%=currentinfo.ClientID%>').scrollLeft = xPos;
             $get('<%=currentinfo.ClientID%>').scrollTop = yPos;
         }
     }

     prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
     prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
 </script>
....
......
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add something to "currentinfo" div, do something like this:

```
var currentinfoDiv =  $get('<%=currentinfo.ClientID%>');

//this will make the div scroll to bottom
currentinfoDiv.scrollTop = currentinfoDiv.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: I have used that but the problem is that div will maintain it's scroll position and will scroll to 2nd from bottom only

Comment: What you mean by "scroll to 2nd"? I create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/u4aZw/

Comment: Ok,I give you a link, Where more details are given for this problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138854/maintain-the-scroll-position-of-div-and-scroll-to-bottom-of-div-if-new-data-is-a

Comment: and in your solution you can easily see that Div is scrolled to bottom after few seconds, which is easy, but when I maintain the div scroll, it never scrolls to bottom because my script maintains the scroll